# Where can I find the full derivation of Helfrich's shape equation for closed membranes?

Tags: energy, specific-reference, variational-calculus, soft-matter

I have approximately 10 papers that claim that, from the equation for shape energy:
$$ F = \frac{1}{2}k_c \int (c_1+c_2-c_0)^2 dA + \Delta p \int dV + \lambda \int dA$$
one can use "methods of variational calculus" to derive the following:
$$\Delta p - 2\lambda H + k(2H+c_0)(2H^2-2K-c_0H)+2k\nabla^2H=0$$
But I'm having a lot of trouble tracking down the original derivation. The guy who did it first was Helfrich, and here's his and Ou-yang's paper deriving it:
http://prl.aps.org/abstract/PRL/v59/i21/p2486_1 . However, they don't show an actual derivation, instead saying "the derivation will appear in a full paper by the authors" or something like that. Yet everybody cites the paper I just linked for a derivation. Does anybody know a source that can derive this, or can give me some hints to figure it out myself? To be honest I can't even figure out how to find the first variation.

Edit: So, after some careful thought and hours and hours of work and learning, I realized that the answer that got the bounty was wrong. The author stopped replying to my messages after I gave him bounty.... thanks guys. That said, I've almost got it all figured out (in intense detail) and will post a pdf of my own notes once I'm done!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit: Note that I am doing only the first variation, and I am not doing each and every step, mainly those pertinent in understanding how the general shape equation is determined. If you want to see the full derivation, you will need to understand the Geometric Mathematic Primer discussed in Sections 2 and 3 of the book.

- Geometric Methods in the Elastic Theory of Membranes in Liquid
  Crystal Phases by Zhong-Can Ou-Yang, Ji-Xing Liu, Yu-Zhang Xie, Xie
  Yu-Zhang

**$c_{0}$:** Spontaneous curvature of the membrane surface

**$k_{c}$:** Bending rigidity of the vesicle membrane

**$H$:** Mean curvature of the membrane surface at any point $P$

**$K$:** Gaussian curvature of the membrane surface at any point $P$

**$dA$:** Area element of the membrane

**$dV$:** Volume element enclosed by the closed bilayer

**$\lambda$:** Surface tension of the bilayer, or the tensile strength acting on the membrane

**$\Delta p$:** Pressure difference between the inside and outside of the membrane.

The shape energy of a vesicle is given by:

$$
F = F_{c} + \Delta p \int dV + \lambda \int dA
$$

Where

$$
F_{c}=\frac{k_{c}}{2}(2H-c_{0})^{2} = \frac{k_{c}}{2}(c_{1}+c_{2}-c_{0})^{2}
$$

The variation of $dA$ and $dV$ are needed, refer to the book to locate those.

Next we'll calculate the first variation of $F$. And we can break this into components by starting with the first variation $F_{c}$.

$$
\delta ^{(1)}F_{c} = \frac{k_{c}}{2}\oint (2H+c_{0})^{2} \delta ^{(1)}(dA) + \frac{k_{c}}{2}\oint 4(2H+c_{0})^{2}(\delta ^{(1)}H)dA
$$

Where the first order variation of $\psi$ gives us:

$$
\delta ^{(1)}dA = -2H\psi g^{1/2}dudv
$$
$$
\delta ^{(1)}dV = \psi g^{1/2}dudv
$$
$$
\delta ^{(1)}H = (2H^{2}-K))\psi + (1/2)g^{ij}(\psi _{ij}-\Gamma _{ij}^{k}\psi_{k})
$$

**Note:** $\Gamma_{ij}^{k}$ is the Christoffel symbol defined by (for reference):

$$
\Gamma_{ij}^{k} = \frac{1}{2}g^{kl}(g_{il,j} + g_{jl,i} - g_{ij,l})
$$

And we plug those into the variation of $F_{c}$:

$$
\delta ^{(1)}F_{c} = k_{c}\oint [(2H+c_{0})^{2}((2H^{2}-K)\psi + (1/2)g^{ij}(\psi_{ij}-\Gamma_{ij}^{k}\psi_{k}))]
$$
$$
= k_{c}\oint [(2H+c_{0})(2H^{2}-c_{0}H-2K)\psi + (1/2)g^{ij}(2H+c_{0})\psi_{ij} - g^{ij}\Gamma_{ij}^{k}(2H+c_{0})\psi_{k}]g^{1/2}dudv
$$

And there are two relations ($i,j = u,v$)

$$
\oint f\phi_{i}dudv = -\oint f_{i}\phi dudv
$$
$$
\oint f\phi_{ij}dudv = \oint f_{ij}\phi dudv
$$

So then we have:

$$
\delta ^{(1)}F_{c} = k_{c}\oint \left \{ (2H+c_{0})(2H^{2}-c_{0}H-2K)g^{1/2} + [g^{1/2}g^{ij}(2H+c_{0})]_{ij} + [g^{1/2}g^{ij}(2H+c_{0})\Gamma_{ij}^{k}]_{k} \right \}\psi dudv
$$

And we can re-write:

$$
[g^{1/2}g^{ij}(2H+c_{0})]_{ij} = [(g^{1/2}g^{ij})_{j}(2H+c_{0})]_{i} + [g^{1/2}g^{ij}(2H+c_{0})\Gamma_{ij}^{k}]_{k} \psi dudv
$$

And for functions $f(u,v)$, where $u,v = i,j$, we can directly expand:

$$
[(g^{1/2}g^{ij})_{j}f]_{i} = -(\Gamma_{ij}^{k}g^{1/2}g^{ij}f)_{k}
$$

A Laplacian operator for these surfaces is defined in the book, and is given as:

$$
\nabla^{2} = g^{1/2}\frac{\partial }{\partial i}(g^{1/2}g^{ij}\frac{\partial }{\partial j})
$$

So then we have:

$$
[g^{1/2}g^{ij}(2H+c_{0})_{j}]_{i} = g^{1/2}\nabla^{2}(2H+c_{0})
$$

Using these methods in the first variation:

$$
\delta^{(1)}F_{c} = k_{c}\oint [(2H+c_{0})(2H^{2}-c_{0}H-2K) + \nabla^{2}(2H+c_{0})]\psi g^{1/2}dudv
$$

And now we want the variation of $F$.

$$
\delta^{(1)}F = \delta^{(1)}F_{c} + \delta^{(1)}(\Delta p\int dV) + \delta^{(1)}(\lambda\int dA)
$$

Which gives us:

$$
\delta^{(1)}F = \oint [\Delta p-2\lambda H + k_{c}(2H+c_{0})(2H^{2}-c_{0}-2K) + k_{c}\nabla^{2}(2H+c_{0})]\psi g^{1/2}dudv
$$

And since $\psi$ is a very small, well smooth function of $u$ and $v$, the vanishing of the first variation of $F$ requires that:

$$
\Delta p - 2\lambda H + k_{c}(2H+c_{0})(2H^{2}-c_{0}H-2K) + k_{c}\nabla^{2}(2H+c_{0}) = 0
$$

Which is the general shape equation of the vesicle membrane. $c_{0}$ is a constant unless the symmetry effect of the membrane and its environment varies between each point (we assume it doesn't) otherwise $c_{0}$ becomes a function of $u$ and $v$. So we can reduce to:

$$
\Delta p - 2\lambda H + k_{c}(2H+c_{0})(2H^{2}-c_{0}H-2K) + 2k_{c}\nabla^{2}H = 0
$$

Hope this helps. Again I would locate that book to see the full derivations. I don't know if the visible section of the book on Google shows you everything that you need to know, but I surely hope this points you in the right direction to understanding the problem.

Comment: I'm actually a math undergrad doing a biophysics summer research project... so I guess I'm a mini-mathematician, and I definitely do like to focus on the derivation haha, especially when it's so unclear. It boggles me that people cite things without knowing where they came from. My school library doesn't seem to have anything useful sadly. Thanks for trying, I hope you or somebody can figure something out!

Comment: I'm going to try working this backwards while learning a little of the subject matter. It helps for me to make assumptions about the derivation. By reading however, the second equation you describe is just one of the boundary conditions. Are you wanting to figure out the derivation for all of the boundary conditions or just that one?

Comment: All would be nice but that one's really the one that matters. One of the papers says it's derived by finding the first variation of the integral and setting it to zero, if that helps.

Comment: Actually I think those 4 boundary conditions are for open lipid membranes. So you need only the one for the closed membrane. I'm trying to figure out with what respect to take the integral, and from there I can get a characteristic equation that I think I can expand out into the form above.

Comment: @Signus The book you cite actually contains all the details of the calculation(s), as far as I remember. See my answer http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/67796/16689 for more details. The paper cited by AJK also contains plenty details, see http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/67547/16689 for her/his answer.

Comment: @Signus Excellent answer. You didn't defined $\psi$ though. I guess it is the variation of the (Monge parameterised) surface $z\left(u,v\right) = \Psi\left(u,v\right) + \psi\left(u,v\right)$, with $\psi\left(u,v\right)\ll\Psi\left(u,v\right)$, am I right ?

Comment: @Signus Actually, you should have something like $z=\Psi + \delta\psi$ such that you calculate the variation $\delta F / \delta\psi$, isn't it ? Thanks for your beautiful answer by the way.

Comment: @Oaoa, I definitely appreciate the edits, thank you. I was trying to leave some of the problem to the OP. I do believe you are correct in your statement regarding $\psi$, and I can double check this and then post it to my solution for completeness.

Comment: @Signus This is great, thank you so much! I'm a little confused about the meaning of $\psi$. Also, what are all the $g$s?

Comment: @BiancaDeSanctis, I'll write an explanation of those when I get a chance to look at the book again. I can't include everything because the math to get to this requires about 10+ pages of deriving, but I'll try and give a better understanding of $\psi$ and $g$.

Comment: @Signus Don't worry about the $g$s, I've been reading that book and fully understand them now. Thank you for that reference. Google preview only goes up to page 47, but that seems like it's good enough... Is $\psi$ the inclination angle talked about on page 42?

Comment: @BiancaDeSanctis, I will still add some further explanation of what they are, but I won't derive them just because it gets extensive. As far as $\psi$ goes I've seen it described mainly as the transmembrane potential (page 67), which made sense to me because we are calculating the free energy of a closed membrane.

Comment: @Signus Do you own the book, or have a link to where I can find it? Google preview doesn't show page 67 so I'm still lost as to $\psi$. :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9240/discussion-between-bianca-de-sanctis-and-signus)

Comment: @Signus Nonono ! $\psi$ is clearly a deformation amplitude (dimension of a length) as it's crystal clear from your variation of the area $\delta A$ and curvature $\delta H$ (note that $H$ has dimension length$^{-1}$ whereas $K$ has dimension length$^{-2}$ by definition). You should define $\psi$ the way I did in a previous comment: $z(u,v) = \Psi(u,v) + \delta \psi (u,v)$ with $\delta \psi \ll \Psi$. That's the key point you're lacking. I discussed this in my answer : http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/67796/16689 below

Comment: @BiancaDeSanctis As any book, you should first ask to your library and your colleagues to know who has the book (if they have it of course). Then you can try on google, asking for the title and adding the research trick: *filetype:pdf* or *filetype:djvu* to hope to have some readable document. If nothing is working, there is still some exchange program between universities, both at national and international level (at least in Europe, there is a European catalog of libraries sharing their books, ask to your librarian). Have fun with membrane.

Comment: So, basically $\Psi \sim z(u,v)$? I have to say, I don't really see the point in that, and it doesn't realllyyy tell me what $\psi$ is either.... Also, I'll go into the library and ask tomorrow, good idea!

Comment: @BiancaDeSanctis It's about the description of the membrane. It's a surface after all, right ? One can describe surface in multiple way. One of these, easy to visualise, is called *Monge parametrisation/patch/...*. It consists in describing a 2D surface in a 3D environment by supposing the third dimension to depend on the first two ones $z=f(x,y)$, that's what I noted $z(u,v)$. Now, you want to deform this surface to know the energy associated to the deformation, right ? You can do that by defining $z=\Psi + \psi$ where $\Psi$ verifies the Helfrich equation without deformation. Does-it help ?

Comment: How did you derive $\delta^{(1)}H$?

Comment: @BiancaDeSanctis, I sent you the reference I am using in chat, Page 78 should help you see where I derived $\delta^{(1)}H$.

Comment: @Signus: I've been working through your solution (finally I know all the prereqs, I think) and I'm relatively sure you messed up taking $\delta^{(1)} F_c$. But I could be wrong. I don't think there should be a square on the second $(2H+c_0)$. Am I right? If not, why is there a square there?

Comment: @BiancaDeSanctis: That's good, I'm glad. Which line are you referring to? There is one line where I kept the square to show you that I expanded out in the next step. However I could have very well put it there again on accident. Message in chat with that line and I'll double check that I didn't make a mistake.

Answer (score 4):

I studied this problem long time ago (almost ten years) during a training period. It's a really interesting problem which, as far I remember, is not so complicated to understand. It's a basic variational method applied to the curvature. In your notation, $H$ and $K$ are the [mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_curvature) and [Gaussian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_curvature) curvature, the two invariants on a (curved) surface.

Perhaps a good knowledge of Stokes theorem (how to translate volume to surface) and variational calculation is a first step in the understanding. Tensor notation in the theory of surface is also a prerequisite. I was particularly enjoying a book by Do Carmo *Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces* Pearson (1973) at the time of this training period, even if I would no more consider it as a modern text-book.

The strategy is to express the curvatures $c_1$ and $c_2$ in your notation as some differential elements of the metric tensor onto which you can apply usual variation calculus. I think you should have something like $c_{1}+c_{2}=2H$, the [mean curvature](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MeanCurvature.html), since I believe $c_{1,2}$ are the curvatures along the principal axis of the surface, am I correct ? You also need to express the change in the infinitesimal volume and the [infinitesimal area](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_variation_of_area_formula) in some differential formulas (in term of the metric tensor) that you can vary. Then you should be full of Christophell, and you should try to recognise the Gaussian and mean curvatures of the final result. They may be simplifying physical assumption, like conservation of the volume, which enters the game, too.

An other way is to express everything in term of the normal vector to the surface. Then, you express the curvature in term of the fundamental form of first and second kind, and make the variational calculation with them. This second method is equivalent to the first one of course, since the fundamental forms can be given in term of the metric. The paper you discuss uses the metric approach if I remember correctly.

I may eventually give you my notes of this period. The only embarrassing point is that they are in French, and I'm really lazy to translate in English :-( The project was to calculate the Green function of a deformed sphere. So it's simpler than yours as believe.

All the details of the calculation can be found in the book by the author:

- Ou-Yang Zhong-Can, Liu Ji-Xing and Xie Yu-Zhang, *Geometric Methods in the Elastic Theory of Membranes in Liquid Crystal Phases* Wolrd Scientific (1999). http://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/3579

with some introductory material about variational calculation and differential geometry of surface (called manifold in modern text-book).

Comment: See also the answer by AJK http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/67547/16689 which gives a detailed calculation paper, too. The results of this paper are obviously reproduced in the book I cited.

Comment: See also the answer by Signus http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/67202/16689 who gave the same book reference as an edit.

Comment: Thank you!! Do you have any idea where I might find this book online? I'm an undergrad and definitely don't have 77$ to spend on it...

Comment: @BiancaDeSanctis Please see my comment after Signus answer. This book might not be available online. As far as I check, it is not. See the answer by AJK http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/67547/16689 for the reference of a detailed paper available on the APS server, too. I would suggest you to contact the next library if you're at some university. The librarians know how to find the book.

Comment: Found it, it's being sent from another library and  should be mine within 7 business days :). I didn't even know you could do that, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 3):

The paper you're looking for is probably:

"Bending energy of vesicle membranes: General expressions for the first, second, and third variation of the shape energy and applications to spheres and cylinders"
Ou-Yang Zhong-can and Wolfgang Helfrich 
Phys. Rev. A 39, 5280–5288 (1989)

http://pra.aps.org/abstract/PRA/v39/i10/p5280_1

Hopefully you have university access - I couldn't find a free copy anywhere.  This is actually a more complicated question than most physics papers like to make it appear!  Good luck with your project.  Membranes are a very cool subject.

Comment: This is close to what I needed, but was insanely confusing because before yesterday I didn't know what a Christoffel symbol was, let alone all of their crazy definitions. Looking back on it now, if I'd been up to speed on all my prereqs for this question, that would have been really useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the paper by [Lin et al. (2003) Progress in Theoretical Physics](http://www.phys.sinica.edu.tw/~statphys/publications/2003_full_text/C_H_Lin_PTP_109_591%282003%29.pdf) they mention in the abstract that they extend the work of Ou-yang and Helfrich by expanding the bending energy to fourth order. That means you should be able to work out the lower order solutions from their paper as well.